# Trying to get a 2d array from class but instead getting <class '__main__.className'>

Tags: python, list, python-class

```py
queue = []
goal_grid = {
    1: [0, 0],
    2: [0, 1],
    3: [0, 2],
    4: [1, 0],
    5: [1, 1],
    6: [1, 2],
    7: [2, 0],
    8: [2, 2]
}
sol = 0
visited = []


class State:
    def __init__(self, state, h=0, parent=None):
        self.state = state
        self.h = h
        self.parent = parent

    def getState(self):
        return self.state

    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent

    def setH(self, h):
        self.h = h


def find_h(state):
    grid = state.getState()
    h = 0
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[0])):
            if grid[i][j] == 0:
                continue
            correct_positon = goal_grid[grid[i][j]]
            h = h + abs(correct_positon[0]-i) + \
                abs(correct_positon[1] - j)
    return h


def generateChildren(state):
    i, j = blank_i, blank_j
    # move up
    if 0 <= i-1 < 3 and 0 <= j < 3:
        new_state = State(state, 0, state)
        grid = new_state.state
        grid[i-1][j], grid[i][j] = grid[i][j], grid[i-1][j]
        new_state.h = find_h(new_state)
        queue.append(new_state)
    # move down
    if 0 <= i+1 < 3 and 0 <= j < 3:
        grid = state.getState()
        grid[i+1][j], grid[i][j] = grid[i][j], grid[i+1][j]
        h = find_h(state)
        new_state = State(grid, h, state)
        queue.append(new_state)
    # move left
    if 0 <= i < 3 and 0 <= j-1 < 3:
        new_state = State(state, 0, state)
        grid = new_state.state
        grid[i][j -
                1], grid[i][j] = grid[i][j], grid[i][j-1]
        new_state.h = find_h(new_state)
        queue.append(new_state)
    # move right
    if 0 <= i-1 < 3 and 0 <= j < 3:
        new_state = State(state, 0, state)
        grid = new_state.state
        grid[i][j +
                1], grid[i][j] = grid[i][j], grid[i][j+1]
        new_state.h = find_h(new_state)
        queue.append(new_state)


def goalstate(state, goal):
    return state.state == goal


def traceback(state):
    while state.getParent():
        for items in visited:
            if state.getParent() == items.getState():
                print(state.state)
                state = items


def inVisited(state):
    for items in visited:
        if items.getState() == state.getState():
            return True
    return False


def driver():
    goal = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]
    start_grid = [[3, 7, 6], [8, 4, 2], [0, 1, 5]]
    start = State(start_grid)
    h = find_h(start)
    start.setH(h)
    global sol
    queue.append(start)
    while queue:
        queue.sort(key=lambda x: x.h)
        current_state = State(queue.pop(0))
        if goalstate(current_state, goal):
            sol += 1
            traceback(current_state)
        else:
            if (inVisited(current_state)):
                continue
            generateChildren(current_state)


blank_i = int(input("Enter the i of blank: "))
blank_j = int(input("Enter the j of blank: "))


driver()
```

Here state is a 2d array. So I get the state from the class instance using getState() and save it in some variable. But the type of that variable becomes **<class '**main**.State'>** and I cannot perform any list operations on it. It shows this error. **TypeError: 'State' object is not subscriptable**.
Why is it not returning a list as it was provided before and how to fix this issue?

queue is a global list that is used to keep track of visited states

**Another thing is that inside the find_h() function, where the heuristic value is calculated, the grid obtained by doing state.getState() does not give any error and after checking its type is shown as <class 'list'>**

This is the whole o/p I get once the code is executed and input is provided i=2,j=0

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

line 122, in 
driver()

line 115, in driver
generateChildren(current_state)

in generateChildren
grid[i-1][j], grid[i][j] = grid[i][j], grid[i-1][j]

TypeError: 'State' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? The code you currently in have in the question does not show the issue.

Comment: Yes. It is posted in the comments. My bad for not including it in the main question itself.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the actually problematic code.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with the code

Comment: Please update your post to show how you're calling the functions, as well as the _full_ error traceback.

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded the whole code with the traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is fairly simple to counter.

```
def driver():
goal = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]
start_grid = [[3, 7, 6], [8, 4, 2], [0, 1, 5]]
start = State(start_grid)
h = find_h(start)
start.setH(h)
global sol
queue.append(start)
while queue:
    queue.sort(key=lambda x: x.h)
    current_state = State(queue.pop(0))
    if goalstate(current_state, goal):
        sol += 1
        traceback(current_state)
    else:
        if (inVisited(current_state)):
            continue
        generateChildren(current_state)
```

In the above function, you are creating an object of `State` .i.e : `current_state` by using the constructor parameter `state` as `queue.pop(0)` which is, in turn, an **object of State class** since `queue` appends `start` which is an object itself.

Hence, `current_state` is an object of `State`, that contains `self.state`, which, again, is an object of `State`. So, in simpler terms: `current_state.state` is not a `list`, but an object of `State` class.

A simple solution would be to use: `current_state = State(queue.pop(0).getState())`.

Similarly, use: `generateChildren(current_state.getState())` as the same problem occurs for `generateChildren` function.

Also, as you asked, why does `find_h` function works fine, is because in: `start = State(start_grid)`, `start_grid` is a list and not an object of `State`.

Hope you understood the problem as well as the solution approach. Feel free to ask, if any doubts!

Comment: Ah this solved the problem I was facing. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to call the method and called the object instead. Did you get 'state' like this:

```py
state_object = State(input_state)

output_state = state_object.getState()
```

Edit:
A few things -

1. Classes would be defined as `class State:` unless you are inheriting another class
2. Line 75 has a `goal_grid` which is not defined anywhere
3. Are you just calling `driver()` for your code? All i see are functions, what is the first thing you call?

Comment: Yeah.. So how to properly do this?

Comment: can you please share the code where you call these functions and define the object?

Comment: I pass in the initial state object in this test function and it is supposed to take the state(2d array) from it, make some changes, and create a new State instance with the modified array.

def test(state):
    grid = state.getState()
    grid[i+1][j], grid[i][j] = grid[i][j], grid[i+1][j]
    new_state = State(grid)

Comment: are you returning the 'new_state' variable from the test() function? The comments make it a little unclear, could you edit the entire code in your post, so that it's got the formatting right?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with the code

Comment: Kindly see the things i have mentioned in the edit of my previous answer

Comment: Yes, I have only included the things that actually created a problem. Yes I do call the driver code and I have defined a goal_state in my original code. As mentioned in the question the find_h( ) function works just fine with the .getState() and all, but the same procedure of getting the list upon calling the .getState( ) does not work inside the generateChildren function

Comment: I've had to make a goal_grid (9x9) and an empty queue, plus the function goalstate is missing from your code so i can't make up much from it, but it doesnt seem to throw an error when it calls find_h(), and is returning a list to `gird`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're creating your `State` objects incorrectly in a few different places. When you call `State(something)`, that something is saved in `self.state` in the `__init__` method. Several parts of your code expect it to be a grid, but you're often calling `State(existing_state)`, so it's a `State` object instead.

Probably you want to copy the grid state of the previous object, and use that copy as the new object's grid state. If you want to be able to initialize the state with either an existing object, or with a new grid, I'd do something like this:

```
class State:
    def __init__(self, state):
        if isinstance(state, State):
            state = copy.deepcopy(state.state)
        self.state = state
        self.h = 0
```

None of your code uses the `parent` attribute for anything, so I omitted it. If you really do need it, you could automatically set it to the state you were passed in, in the one-argument case. Also, it's generally not necessary to write getter and setter methods in your classes. Just have your users directly access your attributes (and use `property` objects if you later decide you need a method call to be involved).

Comment: Oh, now I understand what blunder I was doing. I am fairly new to python and this had me scratching my head for a while now. Thank you soo much for such an informative answer!!!